# printing same url if new page and gets stuck at click next every so often

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have noticed selenium keeps printing the current url even when it changes pages when I click the next button.

Am I missing something?  It seems to loop through all the pages correctly, yet the driver.current url is the same each time.  How is that possible?  Did I forget to have my morning coffee..

I have also noticed that it quite often glitches and instead of clicking next it just displays a little icon like so.  Are these two issues linked perhaps?

[image]

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen')

        elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > div.float-left.col-9.p-2.lh-condensed > a")
elem_href1 = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in elements]
for link in elem_href1:
    try:
        directory = 'C:\\Users\\fefs.csv'
        with open(directory, 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            time.sleep(2)

            langs_text = driver.current_url
            print(langs_text)
            writer.writerow(langs_text)

            SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

            last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

            while True:

                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

                time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

                new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                if new_height == last_height:
                    break
                last_height = new_height
            time.sleep(2)
            wait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("#js-repo-pjax-container > div.container.new-discussion-timeline.experiment-repo-nav > div.repository-content > div > div.paginate-container > div > a.next_page")))).click()
```

Comment: Post? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @PetarPetrov What are you asking for sorry?

Comment: I mean that is the same link because it actually is, but has POST variables on it like for example http://url.com you click next and goes http://url.com?page=2 so the link is still the same http://url.com